# support for chunked encoding in responses

Tags: chunked-encoding, kitura

Does Kitura support sending responses using chunked encoding? I'm looking for the equivalent of [this](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/http/response/#chunked) from Vapor 2. Not seeing anything in the docs/source for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Kitura doesn't support chunked transfer encoding.